# Are there any packaged routines (in lapack or elsewhere) for inverting a banded matrix?

Tags: lapack, banded-matrix

I have a matrix of the form

[image]

And I would like to invert it. Currently I am using the lapack routines zgetrf and zgetri. I.e. I am performing LU factorisation.

My question: Are there any packaged routines (lapack or otherwise) that invert banded matrices? I have found routines for tridiagonal and block diagonal matrices but little else.

Comment: i think the answer to that is no. that is because the inverse operation does not preserve bandedness (i.e., the inverse of a banded matrix is, in general, not banded).

Comment: Note that you could compute the inverses of your L and U factors and multiply them to get $A^{-1}$.  However, the inverses of $L$ and $U$ would be triangular, not banded, and $A^{-1}$ would not be banded.

Comment: If you're already using LU, rather than calculating an inverse, are zgbtrf and friends candidates? http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/zgbtrf.f.html

Answer (score 4):

Well, other than the usual "don't invert your matrices unless you need the inverse itself" you can still use the banded routines [`?gbtrf`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d2/d2d/group__double_g_bcomputational_ga7fc91ba3f250ad3844eba25d59f5d7be.html#ga7fc91ba3f250ad3844eba25d59f5d7be) and then use [`?gbtrs`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d2/d2d/group__double_g_bcomputational_ga37ca5bf29c33e026922c06b3bf188513.html#ga37ca5bf29c33e026922c06b3bf188513) with the right hand side being an identity matrix.